# Remove Add to Cart and prices

Tags: magento-1, addtocart

I think you have to use a FTP client to do this, which i haven't used before. But i'm trying to find a way to remove the add to cart option for logged in or not logged in users and remove the prices aswell.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: may be you are looking for this - https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-hide-prices-and-add-to-cart-button-for-non-logged-in-visitors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can remove content for theses files:

- app/design/frontend/aaaa/aaaa/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
- app/design/frontend/aaaa/aaaa/template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml